# If the UIViewController will be relesed when popped from the navigationController?

Tags: objective-c, ios, release

As the following code :

```
UIViewController *controller = [[UIViewController alloc] init];
[controller.view addSubView:myOtherController.view];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:controller];
[controller release];
```

And myOtherController is a global object, it will not be released.
So the question is that when the controller is popped, if it will be released?
And If it will not be released, how can I verify this?
Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

It will be released when popped. `UINavigationController` retains pushed view controllers and, of course, releases them when popped.

**Edit:** Object ownership is a directed association—but not a tree: Object A owns object B while B can be owned by any number of other objects.

The popped controller owns its view which, in turn, owns the subview. When the popped controller is deallocated it releases its view which releases the shared subview. The shared subview is still owned by some other object so it's not deallocated.

That's the idea of reference counting.

Comment: Thank you! But the popped controller has a subView which has not been released. I'm not sure if the popped controller will be released in this situation. So can you explain further? Thank you very much!

Comment: The controller retain it's view, that retains it's subviews etc.. But views don't retain superview or controller, so it will be released.